# Just a question about the meaning of the word "bash"

Tags: meaning

I always see people using the word "bash" in a Mathematics site.
Then I search on the internet about the meaning of this word.
However, none of the explanations is relevant.
Can anyone explain to me the meaning of this word?
Thanks in advance!
Yours, Michael.

Comment: More context is needed.

Comment: Have you asked anyone in the [maths.se] chatroom?

Comment: [Performing Math Calculation in Bash](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/)

Comment: [Bash Shell Scripting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting)

Comment: This is potentially a really interesting question. But you need to expand a bit.  How are people using it on the maths site? Can you quote an example? What explanations don't fit? Where are you getting the explanations that don't fit? If you can add this kind of detail you are more likely to get useful answers and avoid your question being downvoted or closed.

Comment: I just went through all 7 questions where you've participated on Math.se, but I didn't see the word *bash* make an appearance in any of the posts or comments. Maybe I overlooked it. But either way, as the other said, if you want us to tell you what *bash* means, you need to quote the contexts in which you've seen it used. It has a lot of meanings and we can't tell you which one is being used until we see the contexts it was used in.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: It belong elsewhere; but on mathematics.se it is used to refer to the command-line shell in a Unix-style operating system and ALSO to brute-force solution of a problem, as in "bash it out."

Answer (score 2):

**BASH** is an acronym for ***B***ourne **A**gain **SH**ell, which is a pun on the phrase *born again* and the original *Bourne Shell*,  which was named after its creator, [Stephen Bourne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))

A shell is a way of interacting with Unix-like operating systems, for example [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), and allows you to perform many operations on the computer, for example mathematical operations:

```
$ expr 1 + 1
2
```

[Shell Tips](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/)

You can read up about BASH and it's uses at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash).

Answer (score 0):

They maybe said about [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) - an abbreviation of `Bourne again shell`. Basically, it's a command processor where you can type command and tell the computer to execute it, including complex math calculation.